# Selecting values from a table where values from one column is divided into multiple columns

Tags: sql

I'm trying to develop a query in which the values of a single column are split into two or more separate columns to reflect whether or not a particular id has each of the different values.

For example, I have a table like this:

```
------------
| id | Val |
|----|-----|
| 1  |  A  |
| 1  |  B  |
| 2  |  A  |
| 3  |  A  |
| 4  |  B  |
| 5  |  A  |
------------
```

The query would produce a table that looks like this:

```
----------------------
| id | Val_1 | Val_2 |
|----|-------|-------|
| 1  |  A    |  B    |
| 2  |  A    |       |
| 3  |  A    |       |
| 4  |       |  B    |
| 5  |  A    |       |
----------------------
```

Specifically, I would like this query to show only id's that have missing values (i.e. id "1" would be knocked off the table).

So far I have tried this by using a self inner join, but I have not been able to find the select WHERE clauses to produce this.

Any Suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update : filtering out columns that have Val_1 and Val_2

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT id, MAX(CASE WHEN val='A' THEN 'A' END) as Val_1, 
           MAX(CASE WHEN val='B' THEN 'B' END) as Val_2
FROM table1 GROUP BY id
)a
WHERE Val_1 IS NULL OR Val_2 IS NULL;
```

Comment: how does this prevent items having both A and B from appearing as indicated in the question?

Comment: @Daniel E. : Yeah, I misunderstood a bit question - I thought the second table is a desired output. Fixing...