# Using SWITCH() to split data from a column into distinct columns, with associated data in reach row

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm not quite sure how to properly phrase the question, but I am basically trying to develop an SQL query that `SELECTs` information from this table:

```
-------------------
| id | Val | Date |
|----|-----|------|
| 1  |  A  | 10/9 |
| 1  |  B  | 3/14 |
| 2  |  A  | 1/6  |
| 3  |  A  | 4/4  |
| 4  |  B  | 7/12 |
| 5  |  A  | 8/6  |
-------------------
```

And produces a table that looks like this:

```
------------------------------------------------
| id | Val_1 | Val_1_Date | Val_2 | Val_2_Date |
|----|-------|------------|-------|-------------
| 1  |  A    |   10/9     |  B    |   3/14     |
| 2  |  A    |   1/6      |       |            |
| 3  |  A    |   4/4      |       |            |
| 4  |       |            |  B    |   7/12     |
| 5  |  A    |   8/6      |       |            |
------------------------------------------------
```

I have already begun and developed the query to pull out the values in the Val fields into distinct columns:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT id, MAX(SWITCH( val='A', 'A')) as Val_1, 
             MAX(SWITCH( val='B', 'B')) as Val_2
  FROM table1 GROUP BY id
)a
WHERE Val_1 IS NULL OR Val_2 IS NULL;
```

How would I expand on this to pull out their associated dates?

(I am using `SWITCH()` instead of `CASE WHEN` because I am using a driver similar to that of MS Access.)

Thanks!

Comment: this is almost a exact duplication of your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22897468/selecting-values-from-a-table-where-values-from-one-column-is-divided-into-multi

Comment: Indeed. But as you can see, I included the answer provided in that question and built on the question by including the date field. So, while it is ALMOST an exact duplication, it is not an exact duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think following should work:

```
select id, SWITCH( val='A', 'A') as Val_1, SWITCH( val='A', Date) as Val_1_Date, SWITCH( val='B', 'B') as Val_2, SWITCH( val='B', Date) as Val_2_Date FROM table1 GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not prefer switches, so here is a query that does what you want without switches. This also answers your previous question.

```
Select distinct table1.ID, tableA.Val as Val_1, tableA.Date as Val_1_Date, 
     tableB.Val as Val_2, tableB.Date as Val_2_Date
FROM table1 left outer join 
     table1 as tableA on table1.id = tableA.id and tableA.Val = 'A' left outer join     
     table1 as tableB on table1.id = tableB.id and tableB.Val = 'B'
```

[image]

You can use `ISNULL` if that is preferred. This works because the first tables selects a distinct column of ID's, and the two joins get the A and B values. When creating selects using this method, make sure that you use `tableA.Val = 'A'` in the join conditions, and not in the `where` clause. Having `tableA.Val = 'A'` in the where clause will filter out all `NULL`'s.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this out it works. I did need it in the form of a switch statement, but I will hang on to this for future reference.